# Hadoop Map/Reducer class cannot show anything

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I really get stuck this. Why my Map/Reducer class cannot display anything? I put the following code in my Reducer class:

```
@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context)
{
    // Standard algorithm for finding the max value
    long sum = 0;
    for (LongWritable value : values) {
        sum++; 
    }

    try
    {
        context.write(key, new LongWritable(sum));
        System.out.println("Reducer exits...");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Why the line "System.out.println("reducer exits...");" cannot show in the console when I run Hadoop program: hadoop jar xxx.jar input output

Comment: You will not be able to see sysout in console it will only be seen in jobtracker UI.You can go there and see your sysout.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop redirects the Map/Reduce class System.out output to a log file. If you look at the logs, you will find the line that you are printing.

The logs will be found at:

`http://<jobtracker_address>.50030/jobtracker.jsp -> select your completed job -. select the reduce task -> tasknumber -> task logs -> stdout logs`

Or navigate to your log directory path and go to the appropriate directory for your job and look at the stdout logs there.